# How to properly store timestamp (ms since 1970)

Tags: swift

I feel pretty stupid asking this question because I can't imagine that I was unable to figure it out myself.

In my app I have to work with a timestamp that I get via JSON from my server. Because 1970 is quite long ago this is quite a huge number - e.g. 1,410,882,267,548. In fact to huge to store it in an int (max 2,147,483,647).

However it seems like there is no long or another "bigger" data type in swift - so how should I store it to work with it?

Comment: how about int64? And if you don't need to deal with dates before 1970, there's uint64 as well

Comment: doesn't seem to be possible to cast from an Anyobject to Int64

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974779/convert-json-anyobject-to-int64

NSNumber is the way to go...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Int and UInt can hold that value.

```
Your number:          1_410_882_267_548

Int.max:      9_223_372_036_854_775_807

UInt.max:    18_446_744_073_709_551_615
```

That value may be the case in other languages, but Swift offers quite a large maximum value for Int and UInt. I don't think this max will cause any problems for timestamps any time soon.

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct ... 

„on 32-bit platforms, Int can store any value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, and is large enough for many integer ranges.“

From: Apple Inc. „The Swift Programming Language.“ iBooks.

Afaik iphones older than the 5s have 32Bit Platform