# Convert JSON AnyObject to Int64

Tags: swift

this is somewhat related to this question: [How to properly store timestamp (ms since 1970)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874287/how-to-properly-store-timestamp-ms-since-1970)

Is there a way to typeCast a AnyObject to Int64? I am receiving a huge number via JSON this number arrives at my class as "AnyObject" - how can I cast it to Int64 - xcode just says its not possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

JSON numbers are `NSNumber`, so you'll want to go through there.

```
import Foundation
var json:AnyObject = NSNumber(longLong: 1234567890123456789)

var num = json as? NSNumber
var result = num?.longLongValue
```

Note that `result` is `Int64?`, since you don't know that this conversion will be successful.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast from a AnyObject to an Int with the as type cast operator, but to downcast into different numeric types you need to use the target type's initializer.

```
var o:AnyObject = 1
var n:Int = o as Int
var u:Int64 = Int64(n)
```

Comment: But on 32Bit platforms int is smaller than int64 ... this means i would loose information that way or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try [SwiftJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) which is a better way to deal with JSON data in Swift

```
let json = SwiftJSON.JSON(data: dataFromServer)

if let number = json["number"].longLong {
    //do what you want
} else {
    //print the error message if you like
    println(json["number"])
}
```

Comment: SwiftyJSON is (currently) significantly slower than processing by hand.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rob Napier's answer says, you are dealing with `NSNumber`. If you're sure you have a valid one, you can do this to get an `Int64`

```
(json["key"] as! NSNumber).longLongValue
```